# JavaScript including another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload

I am trying to make a *plugin* for a radio where the javascript is including another javascript. I tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked for me.
I don`t know Javascript so basically I'm trying to learn from experience.

This is my code:

```
function loading_live() {
    document.write('<'+'script src="http://djspinnercee.servemp3.com:32768/php-cgi/scaststatus_x.php?index=5&host='+<?php echo (RADIO_ADDRESS); ?>+'&port='<?php echo (RADIO_PORT); ?>'" type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');

}

var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('#LiveNow').fadeOut('slow').loading_live().fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

The Javascript reloads the right div.. but when it comes to loading the other, external, Javascript it collapses and doesn't show a thing.

Comment: Just declaring a function doesn't make it a jQuery plugin, you need to add it to the jQuery prototype. Check out a [tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Answer (score 0):

Did [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) work for you?

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('#LiveNow').fadeOut('slow');
    $.getScript('http://djspinnercee.servemp3.com:32768/php-cgi/scaststatus_x.php?index=5&host=<?php echo (RADIO_ADDRESS); ?>&port=<?php echo (RADIO_PORT); ?>', function () {
        $('#LiveNow').fadeIn("slow");
    });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Well.. I tried it now.. but it didn't work... [link](http://probe.cabalagames.net84.net/plugins/live_now.php)

Comment: I found a typo in the solution and edited it since then.

*edit*: You don't even have jQuery on your page. How were you doing `$('#LiveNow')`?

Comment: Oh.. right.. sorry , i thought just that link would do. This is the right one [link](http://probe.cabalagames.net84.net/) This is the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

First is you're not calling your function. Chaining it after the `fade` doesn't work.

You need to call it explicitly.
*But it won't work anyway.*

That's the second problem.

You **can't** `document.write` when the page is loaded.

It only works when the Javascript is evaluated by the browser.
That's why similar approaches call the function immediately like:

```
function () {
  document.write('this is inserted in the page');
}(); // <- note the parenthesis
```

If you want to add a JS node to the DOM after the page is loaded, you need to create the element and then attach it to the DOM.

Comment: Well.. I think the external script i`m calling is also using document.write ... So ,how can i create the element, gathering the information from the external, before attaching it to the DOM ?

Comment: If the external document is also using `document.write` you can't do the fading trick... :( Just add it without the effect. Or maybe you could use an `iframe` loading it in the `iframe` but it's really awkward..

Comment: Indeed , the iframe it's just awkward.. but right now, it seems to be the only answer. Well i tried removing the fade effects , but it didn't work. Perhaps i changed the code in the right direction but i can't complete it.. Could you post the entire code, please?

Comment: try just putting in the page `document.write('<'+'script src="http://djspinnercee.servemp3.com:32768/php-cgi/scaststatus_x.php?index=5&host='+<?php echo (RADIO_ADDRESS); ?>+'&port='<?php echo (RADIO_PORT); ?>'" type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');` It should create the `<script src=...` thing. Remember not to put it in the `head` or out of the `body` or it won't work.

Comment: @Web_Rookie and looking at your page there are lots of other problems:  you import 3 different version of jquery, your string is not formatted well as you missed a `'` concatenating the HOST, you're using PHP so you don't need to concatenate HOST and PORT in JS, just write them in the url, the script is in a `marquee` (argh!)...

Comment: Ok.. just putting this without document.write , it works. But i want it to reload itself. Thats why i tried all these methods. And.. also do you have an messenger id or something? X_X Perhaps you can also help me with the other mistakes i made..

Comment: @Web_Rookie if you don't have control on the external JS you can only use an `iframe` to reload that content. There's no other solution. Looking at the source of the external file there's no way to obtain a JSONP.